# Redirect Odoo 8069 to HTTPS without VPC config (AWS/VPS)

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl-certificate, odoo

I created a Github repo weeks ago with Docker Compose, Odoo, PostgreSQL, Certbot, Nginx as a proxy server, and a little bit of PHP stuff (Symfony) -> https://github.com/Inushin/dockerOdooSymfonySSL When I was trying the config I found that NGINX worked as it was supposed to and you get the correct HHTP -> HTTPS redirect, BUT if you put the port 8069, the browser goes to HTTP. One of the solutions should be configured de another VPC, but I was thinking about using this repo for other "minimal VPS services" and not needing another VPC, so... how could I solve this? Maybe from Odoo config? Is something missing in the NGINX conf?

NGINX

```
#FOR THE ODOO DOMAIN
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name DOMAIN_ODOO;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}

server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name DOMAIN_ODOO;
     server_tokens off;

location / {
    proxy_pass       http://web:8069;
    proxy_set_header Host           DOMAIN_ODOO;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
 }

     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN_ODOO/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN_ODOO/privkey.pem;
     include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
     ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  nginx:
     image: nginx:1.15-alpine
     expose:
       - "80"
       - "443"
     ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "443:443"
     networks:
       - default
     volumes:
       - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:rw
       - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw
       - ./data/certbotSymfony/conf:/etc/letsencrypt/symfony/:rw
       - ./data/certbotSymfony/www:/var/www/certbot/:rw
     command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
  
  web:
     image: odoo:13.0
     depends_on:
       - db
     ports:
       - "8069:8069/tcp"
     volumes:
       - web-data:/var/lib/odoo
       - ./data/odoo/config:/etc/odoo
       - ./data/odoo/addons:/mnt/extra-addons
```

Comment: What about adding another server into the nginx config listening to 8069 and redirecting to https... ?

Comment: @CZoellner As I am using docker, this is not what is happening when we make the proxy_pass web:8069, being "web" the docker container for Odoo?

Comment: Read it like 3 times and totally missed the docker part ... Could you possibly add the docker-compose.yml? That will help others to answer. Why is it even possible to get to odoo by using the port in the browser? I would rather not allow it.

Comment: Yep, that is what I do not understand. docker-compose.yml with the Odoo and Nginx part added, @CZoellner

Comment: IIRC the `ports` part on the odoo service is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @CZoellner. Yep, you were right. It looks like that and the firewall config was the problem. My bad. Thank you.